# Keep a Git repository backup up-to-date

Tags: git

As the title says, I have a git repository that is the backup of another one. It was created using git clone.
In order to keep it up-to-date with ongoing modifications, I have a script that runs git pull on the backup to get new modifications. Along with keeping the repository up-to-date, this also gave me the list of modifications that have been done since last update, and I need to keep this information.

After a reinstall on my backup machine, a new issue appeared when running git pull. The issue is already described in other questions, like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66548/git-pull-from-remote-but-no-such-ref-was-fetched).
It made me realize that my actual solution was not complete : whenever remote branches are created, I wasn't getting them.

So my question is : What is the proper command to update the backup repository with **all remote modifications, from all branches** and get the list of changes?

The script is running on the backup machine, that's why i'm doing pulls and not pushes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out the the update command that did the work was **git remote update**. This was only part of the problem, so here is the full solution :

1. Create git repository backup using **git clone --mirror**
2. **git rev-parse HEAD** to get current HEAD commit id
3. **git remote update** to update the backup
4. **git rev-parse HEAD** again to get new HEAD commit id
5. **git diff --name-status *oldHeadId* *newNeadId*** to get the list of files changed in the update

Comment: git fetch --all command does not do what is expected for the whole solution to run : it does not change the head.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking to get the changes you should be using `fetch`.

You can also use the `--all` flag to get the branches and tags from all remotes. As per [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

`git fetch --all`

Comment: Well, this is good to know but there is still something strange : 
Whenever I do a git log on the backup repository, it doesn't show new commits. It looks like they were not fetched...
Oh, and the fetch command doesn't give any error. I am puzzled by that the command is actually doing.

Comment: `git log` checks against your currently checked out branch. You should be using `git log --reflog` to check all branches. You could also try `git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate` to get a better representation of your tree

Comment: Sorry, use `--all` not `--reflog` if you are seeing commits from dead unnamed branches.

Comment: git fetch --all command dit not do what is expected for the whole solution to run : it does not change the head.
The command I was looking for was git remote update